# YAML validation not work Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, fosuserbundle

I have a problem with registration validation. I use `Symfony 2.6`, `FOSUserBundle`, `SonataUserBundle`.

Here my AppBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml:

```
AppBundle\Entity\User:
properties:
    workPhone: - NotBlank: { message: 'Укажите телефон организации', groups: AppRegistration}
    adminPhone: -NotBlank: { message: 'Укажите телефон администратора', groups: AppRegistration}
    name: -NotBlank: { message: 'Укажите название заведения', groups: AppRegistration}
    adress: -NotBlank: { message: 'Укажите адрес заведения', groups: AppRegistration}
    kitchen: -NotBlank : { message: 'Укажите тип кухни', groups: AppRegistration}
    username: -NotBlank: { message: 'Укажите логин', groups: AppRegistration}
    -MinLength: { limit: 4, message: "Логин не должен быть короче {{ limit }} символов", groups: AppRegistration }
    -MaxLength: { limit: 12, message: "Максимальная длина логина {{ limit }} символов", groups: AppRegistration }
    firstname: -NotBlank: { message: 'Укажите имя', groups: AppRegistration}
```

that my app/config/config.yml:

```
framework:
    validation:      { enabled: true, enable_annotations: true }
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
       form:
            type: app_bundle_user_registration
            validation_groups: [AppRegistration, Registration]
```

but properties `username` and `firstname` with custom rules not work!
The validation, that i added in annotation work perfekt... Yaml doesn't

Comment: I think maybe that is because the indentation in your Min and Max Length rules for username.

Comment: I tried -Length and -MinLength - no difference

Comment: I mean the whitespace in the left of each line. There are 2 lines without indentation. It is very important in yaml format.

Comment: If i add whitespace in the left, i get "Parse error". Anyone can me help?!

Comment: You need to add a minimum of two whitespaces.